# Can't install HeatWave extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: wix, windows-installer, vscode-extensions, heatwave

I am trying to create an MSI file through WiX. To do that in VSCode, I need to install the "HeatWave" extension. But I can't find it in the extension marketplace.
It is, however, in the [online web browser marketplace.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FireGiant.FireGiantHeatWaveDev17&ssr=false#overview)

I downloaded the VSIX file and tried to install it through that - Didn't work either.
[It just gave me this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsr53.png)
"extension/package.json was not found in ZIP"

What is preventing me from installing the extension? Is there any other way to add WiX to Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HeatWave is an extension for Visual Studio; it doesn't support Visual Studio Code. We're not aware of any Visual Studio Code extensions for WiX today. But please file a feature idea at https://github.com/firegiant/HeatWaveSupport/issues/new/choose so the dev team can track interest in VSCode.